# Excel - MAX and MIN value by month for a certain item

Tags: excel, equation

Can someone help me out with a formula? 
I have a large database and I`m trying to figure out, how to get the MAX amount used in January 2017 for a product X.

I have found the averages using - `AVERAGEIFS(Avg.de.time!E3:E80231;Avg.de.time!A3:A80231;C2;Avg.de.time!C3:C80231;">="&H7;Avg.de.time!C3:C80231;"<="&EOMONTH(H7;0))`

```
Column A - Item no.
Column B - Supplier name 
Column C - Order date
Column D - Receive date
Column E - Delivery time (D-C)
```

I`ve spent too many hours on trying to figure this out.
 So I m asking for Help :)

Comment: You're after an array formula. Any function can be made conditional (like SUMIFS, AVERAGEIFS) using an IF call which returns an array.

Comment: [This link](https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match) should help!

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I`ll see what I can do :)

Comment: @ArtursIvanovs If you do not find answer yet. Then please put some sample data in the post for better understanding.

Comment: @harun24hr I don`t know how to post a table in the comment box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array formulae you can rewrite your `AVERAGEIFS` statement using a conditional array expression as follows:

```
=AVERAGE(
  IF(
    (
      (Avg.de.time!A3:A80231 = C2) *
      (Avg.de.time!C3:C80231 >= H7) *
      (Avg.de.time!C3:C80231 <= EOMONTH(H7,0))
    ) > 0,
    Avg.de.time!E3:E80231
  )
)
```

I've just formatted the code to make it easier to see where each of the `criteria`, `criteria_range`s and `value_range` appear however this will obviously be one long line in your cell.

It's now very simple to swap out `AVERAGE` at the start with `MAX`, `MIN` or another aggregate function with the rest of the formula remaining identical.

```
=MAX(
  IF(
    (
      (Avg.de.time!A3:A80231 = C2) *
      (Avg.de.time!C3:C80231 >= H7) *
      (Avg.de.time!C3:C80231 <= EOMONTH(H7,0))
    ) > 0,
    Avg.de.time!E3:E80231
  )
)
```

As this is an array formula, you will need to type it into your Excel cell and hit *Ctrl-Enter* to make it an array formula. You can check this worked as curly braces `{}` will appear around the formula.

Comment: thank you genius!
Everything worked fine.
Appreciate the step-by-step explenation :)

Comment: You're welcome! If that's solved your problem you can mark the question as answered with the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Done! Thank you.